# python/mongodb pymongo : nested find()/filter

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to do something like this

```
 contents = contents.find() # get all from collection
if user filled search box 1:
     contents = contents.find({'field1':seached_var})
if user filled search box 2:
     contents = contents.find({'field2':seached_var2})
```

contents would contain the final filtered result. 
Is it doable in python with mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it this way:

```
conditions = {}
if user filled search box 1:
     conditions['field1'] = seached_var
if user filled search box 2:
     conditions['field2'] = seached_var2

contents = contents.find(conditions)
```

Hope that helps.